# How do they do that? Transparent foreground on a web page

Tags: ajax, transparency

You know how sometimes you are on a good site and you click a button (like to submit a form) and the form doesn't go away, instead, the foreground becomes transparent and it contains a message of some kind, or another page. The message is at the forefront but the previous page is still mostly visible behind it - how do they do that? I'm assuming it's an Ajax-esque trick.

Comment: "...you're all quite smart.." doesn't hurt. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a light box modal.  There are quite a few JS plugins that can do this including [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) and the [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) to name a couple.  I just recently started using [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) and have been very impressed with its speed and configurability.

Here is a pretty good (not all inclusive) list of them:

http://spoonfedproject.com/jquery/extensive-list-of-jquery-lightbox-modal-plugins/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. In the back of my head I figured this would include jQuery in some capacity.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [GreyBox](http://orangoo.com/labs/GreyBox/). I think this similar to the effect that you're talking about.